# How to convert int to char in c++ style?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, static-cast

Please tell me how to convert int to char in c++ style? The content in str1 is "\001", while the content in str2 is "1"; Can I use static_cast to get the same result as str2?
The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    string str1;
    string str2;

    str1.push_back(static_cast<char>(a));
    str2.push_back('0' + a);
    cout << str1 << str2;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the exact use-case. For a direct int-to-string conversion, use [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

When streaming the output, there are usually better options, including using [fmt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) (part of C++20, available as a [separate library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) before that).